# Clipboard - copy/paste of custom data type randomly works

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

The interaction with the clipboard is randomly successful. Below code adds different formats to clipboard:

```
std::pair<wxGridCellCoords, wxGridCellCoords> AddSelToClipbrd(const WorksheetBase* ws)
{
    //some code
    wxString HTMLStr = GenerateHTMLTable(ws, TL, BR);
    wxString XMLStr = xml::GenerateXMLString(ws, TL, BR);
    wxString TabStr = GenerateTabString(ws, TL, BR);

    wxDataObjectComposite* dataobj = new wxDataObjectComposite();
    dataobj->Add(new xml::XMLDataObject(XMLStr), true);
    dataobj->Add(new wxTextDataObject(TabStr));
    dataobj->Add(new wxHTMLDataObject(HTMLStr));

    if (wxTheClipboard->Open())
    {
        wxTheClipboard->SetData(dataobj);
        wxTheClipboard->Flush();
        wxTheClipboard->Close();
    }
}
```

The XMLDataFormat is implemented as follows:

```
export struct XMLDataFormat : public wxDataFormat
{
    XMLDataFormat() : wxDataFormat("XMLDataFormat") {}
};


export class XMLDataObject : public wxDataObjectSimple
{

public:
    XMLDataObject(const wxString& xmlstring = wxEmptyString) :
        wxDataObjectSimple(), m_XMLString{ xmlstring }
    {
        SetFormat(XMLDataFormat());
    }

    size_t GetLength() const 
    {
        std::string s = (const char*)m_XMLString.mb_str(wxConvUTF8);
        return  s.length() + 1;
    }

    wxString GetXML() const {
        return m_XMLString;
    }

    void SetXML(const wxString& xml) {
        m_XMLString = xml;
    }

    // Must provide overloads to avoid hiding them (and warnings about it)
    size_t GetDataSize() const {
        return GetLength();
    }

    bool GetDataHere(void* buf) const
    {
        std::string s = (const char*)m_XMLString.mb_str(wxConvUTF8);
        memcpy(buf, s.c_str(), s.length() + 1);
        return true;
    }

    bool SetData(size_t len, const void* buf) {
        m_XMLString = wxString::FromUTF8((const char*)buf, len + 1);
        return true;
    }

    size_t GetDataSize(const wxDataFormat&) const {
        return GetDataSize();
    }

    bool GetDataHere(const wxDataFormat&, void* buf) const {
        return GetDataHere(buf);
    }

    bool SetData(const wxDataFormat&, size_t len, const void* buf)
    {
        return SetData(len, buf);
    }

private:
    wxString m_XMLString;
};
```

To get the XML data from the clipboard:

```
wxString GetXMLData()
{
    if (!wxTheClipboard->Open())
        return wxEmptyString;

    if (!wxTheClipboard->IsSupported(XMLDataFormat()))
            return wxEmptyString;

    XMLDataObject xmlObj;

    wxTheClipboard->GetData(xmlObj);
    wxTheClipboard->Close();

    return xmlObj.GetXML();
}
```

The problem seems to be that GetXMLData returns empty string but this is random; so I run the application and it gives error and then quit the application and run it again (same copy/paste) and it pastes (always tested with the same data).

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if it returns empty string because it fails to open the clipboard, because `IsSupported()` returns false or because `GetData()` returns empty string?

Comment: @VZ. Neither `IsSupported` nor failing to open the clipboard. `wxTheClipboard->GetData(xmlObj);` brings empty string. However, what is strange is that if I quit the application and run the application again and *without copying* directly call paste, it works. Btw, right after copying I checked with Free Clipboard Viewer and XMLDataFormat is indeed there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error comes from implementation of `XMLDataObject`. Therefore,  instead of deriving from `wxDataObjectSimple` now it is changed to `wxTextDataObject` and so far it works stable.

So the new implementation is as simple as the following:

```
export struct XMLDataFormat : public wxDataFormat
{
    XMLDataFormat() : wxDataFormat("XMLDataFormat") {}
};


export class XMLDataObject : public wxTextDataObject
{

public:
    XMLDataObject(const std::string& UTF8 = "") :
        wxTextDataObject(UTF8)
    {
        SetFormat(XMLDataFormat());
    }
};
```